# $K[x,y]/(xy-1) \cong K[t,t^{-1}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

In an exercise I found stated that, given a field $K$, $$K[x,y]/(xy-1) \cong K[t,\dfrac{1}{t}],$$
where $K[x,y]$ is the polynomial ring in two variables on $K$ and $( \cdot )$ indicates the generated ideal.

However I'm confused at what is meant by $K[t, t^{-1}]$. Is it a polynomial ring? What kind of algebraic structure it has and what is meant by the isomorphism?

Comment: $K[t,t^{-1}]$ must be thought inside the fraction field of $K[t]$, and is infact the smallest ring containing $t$ and $t^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means polynomials in $t$ and $\frac{1}{t}$, for example $t^4-5t^3+t+\frac{4}{t}-\frac{9}{t^2}$ is in $K[t,t^{-1}]$. In other words 'polynomials' in $t$ that can have negative degree as well.

It has the structure of a ring, or more specifically a $K$-algebra. By isomorphism it's meant an isomorphism of $K$-algebras. That means an isomorphism of rings that is the identity on elements of $K$ (the constant polynomials).

Answer (score 0):

You can define $\displaystyle K [t, \frac{1}{t}]$ to be the set of all formal expressions 
$$ \frac{a_{-n}}{t^{n}} + \frac{a_{-(n-1)}}{t^{n-1}} + \cdots + \frac{a_{-1}}{t}+ a_0 + a_1 t + \cdots + a_m t^{m}$$
where all the coefficients $a_{-n}, …, a_{m}$ are in the field $K$, and $t$ is an "indeterminate" (in the same way as $x$ is indeterminate in the polynomial ring $K[x]$). Now you can verify that $K$ is a ring under the usual operation that you are familiar from high school. :)